# Heroku - bad MySQL query (ActiveRecord)?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord, heroku

After a long time, when I was looking for a failure in my app, it finally looks I found the problem - is that the MySQL query shown below. I know Heroku use PostgreSQL database, but most of the time there are working all my apps based on MySQL DB, but now I got an error about this query:

```
Tshirt.joins(:favorites => [:customers]).where(["tshirts.user_id != ?", current_user.id]).order('rand()').limit(3).uniq
```

Could anyone give me any help, how to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you test your code with MySQL when it finally runs with PostgreSQL. You should always develop against the DBMS that you use in production

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres, the rand function is `RANDOM()` so you should chnage your order clause

Comment: yes, one problem is `random()` (solved), the second one is `.uniq` - in MySQL works well, in PostgreSQL not. When I comment that and test it, so it work, but with `.uniq` in PostgreSQL gives me this query error